# windows heroku run rake db:migrate error "/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory"

Tags: windows-7, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm pretty new to Rails here and I've followed [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) for most of it. I have since decided to make my own application, but using the Rails 4 gem in beta. I have installed PostgreSQL on my local machine (Windows 7) and done development. Everything works great! (I love Rails much more than C#, ASP, .NET work that I do for a living!)

However, once I decided to push to Heroku, I've been pulling my hair out. Prior to pushing to Heroku, I did the standard:

```
c:\Sites\elms>git add .
c:\Sites\elms>git commit -m "My comment"
c:\Sites\elms>git push
c:\Sites\elms>git push heroku master
```

I've downloaded and installed the Heroku Toolbelt (not `heroku` gem.) The first error told me I needed to make sure that my `Gemfile` specified Ruby >= 1.9.3, so I added "ruby 1.9.3" to the top of my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "1.9.3"

gem 'rails', '4.0.0.beta1'

gem 'pg'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'httparty'
gem 'devise', git: 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'formtastic-plus-bootstrap'

group :development do
  gem 'annotate'
  gem 'better_errors'
  gem 'binding_of_caller'
  gem 'guard-spork'
  gem 'guard-rspec'
  gem 'meta_request'
  gem 'rb-notifu'
  gem 'schema_to_scaffold'
  gem 'wdm', :platforms => [:mswin, :mingw], :require => false
  gem 'win32console'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'spork-rails', git: 'git://github.com/sahilm/spork-rails.git', branch: 'rails-4'
  gem 'spork', '~> 1.0.0rc3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem "shoulda-matchers"
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0.beta1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'    
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.0.1'
```

The push finally worked without any issues, but when I tried to migrate the database, I got the following:

```
c:\Sites\elms>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2205
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

I have also tried: `heroku run bin/rake db:migrate`, and it gives same error. I am using [Getting Started with Rails 4.x on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails4) to push my Rails 4 app to Heroku. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Oh, I also had an issue after running:

```
c:\Sites\elmx>gem install rails --pre
```

I solved this by adding `C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;` to my environment Path variable in Windows 7 (it was giving me an error that it couldn't find rails when trying to execute anything such as:

```
rails -v
rails g controller User
```

But if I typed just:

```
rails
```

It would give me all of the commands I could use (as if running `rails -h`)

I set up my machine by using the Windows Rails Installer, then installing the Rails 4 gem. This is extremely frustrating and I've scoured the internet trying to find someone with the same problem.

EDIT 1:

I just deleted my user Path environment variable and modified my system Path environment variable to look like such:

```
 C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin;C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Heroku\bin
```

Updated my path variable to the above and uninstalled Heroku Toolbelt, then re-installed it (hence why the Heroku piece is in the path variable) and tried the following:

```
c:\Sites\elms>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]

c:\Sites\elms>rails -v
Rails 4.0.0.beta1

c:\Sites\elms>heroku -v
 !    `-v` is not a heroku command.
 !    Perhaps you meant `-h`.
 !    See `heroku help` for a list of available commands.

c:\Sites\elms>heroku run rake db:migrate
Running `rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2100
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory

c:\Sites\elms>heroku run bin/rake db:migrate
Running `bin/rake db:migrate` attached to terminal... up, run.2872
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

EDIT 2:

So I got a little further in this venture. I found out that I could execute:

```
c:\Sites\elms>heroku run bash
~ $ cd bin
~/bin $ ruby rake db:migrate
```

And that would then run rake and migrate my database on Heroku. But the problem gets worse! I try to navigate to the page and it tells me that there is something wrong, so I run the log file and this is what I get:

```
c:\Sites\elms>heroku logs
2013-03-16T05:34:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Enable Logplex by
2013-03-16T05:34:20+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v2 created by 
2013-03-16T05:34:36+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2013-03-16T05:35:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 13423 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-16T05:35:37+00:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2013-03-16T05:35:37+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory

2013-03-16T05:35:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-03-16T05:35:39+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 33539 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-16T05:35:40+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
2013-03-16T05:35:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-03-16T05:35:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-03-16T05:35:41+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-03-16T05:35:44+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 23452 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-03-16T05:35:44+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

This is getting really frustrating. I have no clue what the heck `/usr/bin/env` is. The only thing I can guess is that it's like `PATH` for Windows. If this is the case, why does the server not know where `ruby.exe` is?

I did make a non Rails 4 application and was able to post it to Heroku and view it with no issues. This is really getting on my nerves.

Answer (score 43):

You need to change in your application first line of the 3 files:

```
bin/bundle
bin/rails
bin/rake
```

Instead

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

must be

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

That's why is error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

Then you do successfully:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

It's work for me.

Comment: I was having a very hard time getting cron to send automated messages from within Rails and then I came across this answer.  You saved my life, and if I could I would give you 10 votes.  Thanks.

Comment: In my situation all i needed was to change first line of `you_app/script/rails` from `#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`. Look carefully at this line - it's easy to ignore it, because editor treat this line as comment :)

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and as others have already stated, changing the below helped.

`#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe` to `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`

**However**, I also needed to remove some hidden carriage returns which were still present from developing on Windows originally (I guess?).

I used `dos2unix` to do this.

```
dos2unix bin/bundle bin/rake bin/rails
```

After that, I committed my changes, pushed to heroku and all was good.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem, changed ruby.exe to ruby in the three files as described above, executed the

```
    git push heroku master
```

step, which told me everything was up to date.  Trying the

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate
```

step again, it still didn't work; I got the same error about no such file or directory for ruby.exe.  I examined my gemfile.lock as directed, but didn't see anything that looked windows-y.

I then executed these:

```
    git add .
    git commit -m "My comment"
```

and tried again with

```
    git push heroku master
```

This time, boatloads of messages went by, including:

```
    Removing Gemfile.lock because it was generated on Windows.
```

so perhaps there was something wrong with it and I just didn't know what I should be looking for in it.

Trying again to

```
    heroku run rake db:migrate
```

looks to have worked, as I got

```
    Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.3260
    ==  CreateUsers: migrating ====================================================
    -- create_table(:users)
       -> 0.0409s
    ==  CreateUsers: migrated (0.0412s) ===========================================
```

My best guess is that the change to remove the .exe from bundle, rake, and rails did not actually get pushed up on the first try of 
git push heroku master
and the 
git add . 
and 
git commit -m "My comment" 
were necessary to make it get pushed up.  This is my first attempt at anything with git/heroku/ruby, so I don't know enough to say why the other two commands were required, but leave my experience documented here in case it helps anybody else.
Thanks so much for the clue above that it was the .exe in those three files that caused the problem.

Comment: I followed the same steps on windows xp and after finding this post, had to remove .exe also.  Afterwards no change until I followed your instructions.  Working nicely now!

Answer (score 1):

```
bin/bundle
bin/rails
bin/rake
```

Instead

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby.exe
```

must be

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

(thanks to previous post)

make sure there are no references to windows in the gemfile.lock - they can just be deleted

then

```
git push heroku master
```

if there are still problems use

heroku logs (copying text to a text editor makes it easier to cut and paste for solutions)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev
```

and then install Nokogiri:

```
gem install nokogiri
```