# Heroku dyno crashes with message app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I have a basic rails application which works on my windows 8 desktop (rails_12factor, ruby 1.9.3, rails 4, postgres) - using `rails server` - I am able to navigate to the application website on my local browser and everything renders fine.

I push the application up to heroku via `git push heroku master` and everything seems to go fine. The only warning I see is "Removing `Gemfile.lock` because it was generated on Windows." The process ends with the following message - "Launching... done, v9".

However on running "heroku ps" I get the following:

=== web (1X): `bin/rails server -p $PORT -e $RAILS_ENV`
web.1: crashed 2013/07/12 00:42:20 (~ 4s ago)

On doing heroku logs --tail, I get the following being repeated in the log files - :

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 16041 -e $RAILS_ENV`
app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL

...

heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
```

I saw stuff on the web that had me check .gitignore to see if the contents of my local bin folder were getting excluded. They are not. I also saw suggestions to edit the contents of the bin folder and remove the word .exe after ruby - I tried that as well.

EDIT 1: My project has a subfolder bin, with 3 files bundle, rail and rake. These are the only files which start with #!/usr/bin/env ruby. I also edited the first line to read #!/usr/bin/env ruby**.exe** - the error was still seen. Here is the content of each file :

bundle

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')
```

rails

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rails/commands'
```

rake

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative '../config/boot'
require 'rake'
Rake.application.run
```

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443456/windows-heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error-usr-bin-env-ruby-exe-no-such-file-o

Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17736328/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-by-michael-hartl-chapter-2-exercise-demo-app-app-works

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that some script is trying to load `ruby.exe` via a shebang.

Take a look at `yourproject/script/rails`, mine looks like this under Mac OS 10.6:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# This command will automatically be run when you run "rails" with Rails 3 gems installed from the root of your application.

APP_PATH = File.expand_path('../../config/application',  __FILE__)
require File.expand_path('../../config/boot',  __FILE__)
require 'rails/commands'
```

Comment: I dont have a folder `scripts` in my project folder. However, I have a bin folder with files bundle, rails and rake. They all start with  `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`:  e.g. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
load Gem.bin_path('bundler', 'bundle')`

Comment: What if you search for `ruby.exe` inside your project folder

Answer (score 0):

A guess here: you edited the source files on Windows, so the line endings are wrong. If they are, the Linux loader will try to load "ruby\n".

Run dos2unix on your files, re-commit and re-push to Heroku. It actually happened to me once.