# Ruby on Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl Chapter 2 exercise (demo_app): app works on Windows 8 localhost, but doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, heroku

I am new to web development and I am trying to learn RoR with [Michael Hartl's book Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/a-demo-app). My problem is on Chapter 2 (the demo_app, a microblog-like using scaffolding).

The demo_app runs perfectly on localhost:3000, but when I push it to Heroku, it doesn't work (both the index and /users or /microposts) and shows the message:

*"Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details."*

Here is Heroku's log:

```
2013-07-18T23:45:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-07-18T23:47:13.079550+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.164452+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_COBALT resource by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.198422+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.289007+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.315343+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.368054+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5c359d1 by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.404636+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:14.455717+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 5c359d1 by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:47:15+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2013-07-18T23:47:24.815578+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-18T23:47:24.816243+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-18T23:47:29.239184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40177 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-18T23:47:30.141486+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-07-18T23:47:32.030497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-18T23:47:32.047706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-18T23:47:33.081140+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:47:33.459600+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:47:39.437747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-18T23:47:39.437747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-07-18T23:48:39.904762+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by sergio.schuler@gmail.com
2013-07-18T23:48:43.962916+00:00 heroku[run.7255]: Awaiting client
2013-07-18T23:48:44.045577+00:00 heroku[run.7255]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2013-07-18T23:48:45.332120+00:00 heroku[run.7255]: State changed from starting to up
2013-07-18T23:48:49.566475+00:00 heroku[run.7255]: Process exited with status 0
2013-07-18T23:48:49.575731+00:00 heroku[run.7255]: State changed from up to complete
2013-07-18T23:49:12.500850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="
200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:16.494827+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="
200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:18.188864+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/users host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:18.523155+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="
200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:20.389909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/users host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:20.706606+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="
200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:19.925876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:21.662834+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/users host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:49:21.973127+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=powerful-hamlet-1820.herokuapp.com fwd="200.102.212.90" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-07-18T23:58:04.507344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-18T23:58:07.786500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 32660 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-18T23:58:08.981452+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-07-18T23:58:10.252381+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-18T23:58:10.273793+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-19T00:08:40.833356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-19T00:08:44.112189+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 21751 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-19T00:08:46.119816+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-07-19T00:08:47.198086+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-07-19T00:08:47.181492+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-19T00:19:17.976344+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-07-19T00:19:21.334982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 35103 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-19T00:19:21.887922+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
2013-07-19T00:19:22.932515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-07-19T00:19:31.846924+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Failed to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-07-19T00:19:31.847214+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

Here is the repository: https://github.com/sergioschuler/demo_app

I tried this too:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
git add .
git commit -am "add a note reflecting changes made"
git push
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku rake db:migrate
heroku db:push
```

(Eventually I broke even my local app, so I rolled back)

I am using Windows 8 and installed with Railsinstaller.

Sorry if there is some info missing, I am still a bit new to all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
2013-07-18T23:47:29.239184+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 40177 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-07-18T23:47:30.141486+00:00 app[web.1]: bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
```

Try adding a [Procfile](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile) to your application that has this:

```
web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT
```

Comment: I ran `web: bundle exec rails server -p $PORT` but got an error `C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:33:in `parse!': invalid argument: -p $PORT (OptionParser::InvalidArgument)`

Comment: That should be in the contents of a file named Procfile, committed to your repo, and then pushed to Heroku.

Comment: WORKED! :D I wish I understood what was that all about, but I guess for now this will do. :) Thanks a mil.

Comment: It's all explained in the article I linked: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile