# Heroku running rake error: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I'm running Windows and I'm trying to run '**heroku run rake db:migrate**' for my newly created app on Heroku.

I get the following error:
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory

I've been searching online for over an hour, but haven't been able to find a fix.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16268193/1971365 ?

Comment: Actually it did :) Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16268193/1971365 

This did the trick! Thanks @yarakyo