# open command does not work in heroku

Tags: heroku

I updated my rails app on heroku with push, but when I used the command heroku open my command prompt read

```
no such file or directory .heroku/client/vendor/gems/addressable-2.3.2/data/unicode.data(Errno::ENOENT)
```

not sure what is going on. I did heroko logs and I got a long list of some weird feedback that I don't understand. Anyway hope this is all helpful. Does anyone know what's going on?

here is my heroku logs

```
2013-08-26T23:29:23+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2013-08-26T23:30:40.856501+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by lanners.marshall
@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.479196+00:00 heroku[api]: Attach HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GOLD reso
urce by lanners.marshall@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.517670+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v3 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.596604+00:00 heroku[api]: Add DATABASE_URL config by lanners
.marshall@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.622576+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v4 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.670403+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 6bdd211 by lanners.marshall
@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:41.698072+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v5 created by lanners.mars
hall@yahoo.com
2013-08-26T23:30:45.518833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 39588 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-26T23:30:46.148345+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-26T23:30:47.474136+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-26T23:30:47.484121+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-26T23:30:47.484721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-26T23:30:51.551472+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 43747 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-26T23:30:53.341195+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-26T23:30:55.337892+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-26T23:30:55.329904+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-26T23:41:15.238982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-26T23:41:18.948180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 28272 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-26T23:41:19.673459+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-26T23:41:21.166624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-26T23:41:21.182154+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-26T23:41:29.185339+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-26T23:41:29.185135+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-26T23:51:49.427744+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-26T23:51:52.685493+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 24715 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-26T23:51:53.320123+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-26T23:51:54.877945+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-26T23:51:54.895579+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-27T00:02:12.823833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-27T00:02:17.454356+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 35817 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-27T00:02:18.536931+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-27T00:02:20.493992+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-27T00:02:27.748278+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2013-08-27T00:02:27.748030+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-27T00:12:27.719245+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2013-08-27T00:12:30.128833+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 51549 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-08-27T00:12:31.578894+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2013-08-27T00:12:31.542115+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2013-08-27T00:12:30.563854+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such fil
e or directory
2013-08-27T00:12:40.521830+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R99 (Platform error) -> Fa
iled to launch the dyno within 10 seconds
2013-08-27T00:12:40.522094+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
```

Answer (score 1):

Read the error log, and do a SO search.  The giveaway is the `ruby.exe`.  This is a windows executable name.  Heroku runs Linux, where executables don't end in `.exe`

To fix this, in your `procfile`, change `ruby.exe` to `ruby`. And use unix line endings while we're at it. And then commit your files and re-push. [This article](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings) has some helpful information on how to let git manage line ending conventions for you.

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443456/windows-heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error-usr-bin-env-ruby-exe-no-such-file-o/16268193#16268193