# Will changing the bin files in a Rails project affect how its implemented on other devices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I am beginning to contribute to a Rails/Heroku project that, and I was cloning it to my machine running linux Mint. As I was getting it up and running locally I encountered [similar issues as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15443456/windows-heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-error-usr-bin-env-ruby-exe-no-such-file-o), namely the error

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby.exe: No such file or directory
```

when trying to start my local server. This was an easy fix, just changed "ruby.exe" to just "ruby" in bin/bundle bin/rails and bin/rake but I'm worried about pushing back to github, since the project automatically hosts whatever is on the remote repo.

Am I going to cause issues with the hosted version if I push my changes to the bin files? If I am is the most appropriate solution adding the bin files to .gitignore since the changes are only necessary on my machine? Most of the other contributors are using OSX or Windows.

Comment: rather than changing the bin files (for which we cannot guess what might happen) why not create an `alias` for `ruby.exe` ?

Comment: I tried creating an alias:
    alias ruby.exe="ruby"
With no luck.

Comment: Darn. what about a symlink ?

Comment: I tried ln -s ruby ruby.exe again with no luck. I think what I will do is just tell git to assume these files are unchanged, so that I can push any other changes without worrying about making a mess with any of the bin files